# "Responsive UI" doesn't wrap tags on Android

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, mobile-web

Clicking on the button called "full" changed the UI, as I expected, but it's not good for android (maybe not good for skinny screens). I couldn't change it back. I saw a button, "disable responsiveness", but this UI was not good for android: it was showing like a laptop's UI.

Tags was just in a row. Earlier, they used to be in a separated line if there was too many tags.

[image: non wrapping tags]

Comment: At some point we lost wrapping in our tags. Frustrating, but somehow not _new_. We're on it!

Comment: @aaron, What I see using FF Android looks reasonable, without using "Desktop Site" view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQGTL.jpg

Comment: @Rob yes! That's  what I mentioned in my post also. And I would like to rollback the UI. But I couldn’t :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve restored wrapping to the tags section, so this should now be fixed.